# How do I SUMIF one PowerPivot table according to the rows of a second PowerPivot table?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have two tables: one of customers ("Donor"), and one of transactions ("Trans"). In Donor, I want a "Total" column that sums all the transactions by a particular Donor ID, which I would calculate in a standard Excel table thus:

```
=SUMIF(Trans[Donor ID],[@ID],Trans[Amt])
```

Simple! How do I do the same thing with a DAX formula? I thought

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Trans[Amt]),Trans[Donor ID]=[ID])
```

would do it, but I get the error

```
Column "ID" cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.
```

Strangely, when I use

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Trans[Amt]),Trans[Donor ID]=3893)
```

I *do* get the total for ID 3893.

Eschewing CALCULATE, I did find that this works:

```
=SUMX(FILTER(Trans, Trans[Donor ID]=[ID]),[Amt])
```

...but it only allows the one filter, and I'll need to be able to add more filters, but:

```
=SUMX(CALCULATETABLE(Trans, Trans[Donor ID]=[ID]),[Amt])
```

...(which I understand is like FILTER but allows for multiples) does not work.

Can you identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this, I have exactly the same dilemma now and it would be great if you found the solution!

Comment: Alas, no. I denormalized the two tables into one flat one.

Answer (score 6):

After putting together a quick model that looks like this:

I've confirmed that this DAX forumla works as a Calculated Column in the Donor table:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(Trans[Amt]), FILTER(Trans, Trans[Donor] = Donor[DonorKey]))
```

The key here is to make sure that the relationship between the two tables is correctly configured, and then make sure to use the combination of CALCULATE() and FILTER() -- filtering the trans table based on the current donor context.